# Пересылка бинарных данных в udp-пакетах (LUA)

Tags: lua, udp

Не проходит пересылка бинарных данных в udp-пакетах.

Использую `ESPLorer` `LUA` `send(port, ip, Buf)`

Программа работает на UDP-сервере, ждёт команду запроса данных от
клиента, дожидается и отправляет данные. Это вызывает трабл:

> (PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (init.lua:12: bad argument #3 to 'send' (string expected, got table))

Передача строковых данных проходит нормально. Но мне-то нужно передавать бинарные (результаты измерений). Перевод в `string` - не предлагать

Comment: *"Перевод в string - не предлагать"* - если API ожидает тип `string`, то с этим уже ничего не поделать, только переводить. Или пользоваться другим API/библиотекой/писать свой вариант.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое Esplorer, но очевидно, проблема в несоответствии вашего кода с его API. Читайте внимательнее документацию или спросите у автора. Вот тут, например: https://github.com/4refr0nt/ESPlorer/issues

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете отправить таблицу lua через сеть. А вот бинарные данные это и есть `string` . Так что надо сделать генератор сообщений на основе этой самой таблицы. А еще, перед отправлением тела сообщения рекомендуется отправить его размер, например:

```
function parsetable(t)
  local res=""
  -- Делаем что-то с таблицей
  return res
end
function numberToByteCode(x)
  local line=""
  local res1,res2=intdiv(x,256)
  if res1 > 255 or res1==0 then
    line=string.char(res2)..line
    elseif res1 > 0 then
      line=string.char(res1)..string.char(res2)..line
    end
  while res1 > 0 do
    res1,res2=intdiv(res1,256)
    if res1 > 255 then
      line=string.char(res2)..line
    elseif res1 > 0 then
      line=string.char(res1)..string.char(res2)..line
    end
  end
  return line
end
function byteCodeToNumber(x)
  local y=0
  local z=0
  for n=#x,1,-1 do
    if z==0 then
      y=y+(x:sub(n,n):byte())
    else
      y=y+(x:sub(n,n):byte())*256^z
    end
    z=z+1
  end
  return y
end
function fromNumber32(n)
  local bytecode=numberToByteCode(n)
  if #bytecode > 4 then
    bytecode="\255\255\255\255"
  elseif #bytecode < 4 then
    bytecode=string.rep("\0",4-#bytecode)..bytecode
  end
end
function format(msg)
  return fromNumber32(#msg)..msg
end
function get()
  local size=byteCodeToNumber(receive(4))
  return receive(size)
end
function sendparsed(ip,port,t)
  send(ip,port,format(parsetable(t)))
end
```

Таким образом, максимальная длина сообщения будет ~4 GB, а спец-символы не будут мешать передаче сообщения.